# Determining order of poles.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having some trouble understanding how to tell the order of poles. I understand simple cases I've seen online, but how about in something like ($z^{2}+1$)/($z^{3}-1)$? There's a pole at 1 and I think its of order 1. My questions arise when I split it into the form f(z)=g(z)/$(z-z_{0})^{m}$. In this case would g(z)=($z^{2}+1$) and have ($z^{3}-1)^{-1}$?

Comment: A general method is to calculate $\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)^ng(z)$ and determine the smallest $n$ for which this limit is finite. That $n$ is the order of the pole.

Answer (score 2):

Your rational function factors as $$\frac{z^2+1}{(z-1)(z-\omega)(z-\omega^2)}$$ where $\omega=e^{2i\pi/3}$. So it has poles of order one at $1,\omega,$ and $\omega^2$: the order of a pole is just the multiplicity of the zero of the denominator at that pole, assuming you've cancelled common factors.